# Use value from method in javascript object to use in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have tried different things but I do seem to be looking something over that is too obvious. Trying to use the value a function(method) returns inside an object and use it in another method with setTimeout within that same object.

This is the html:

```
<h1>3000</h1>
```

The javascript (jQuery in this case):

```
    var foo = { 
        getValue: function() {
            var h1Text = $('h1').text();
            h1Text = parseInt(h1Text);
            return h1Text;
        }, 
        useValue: function() {
            var time = this.getValue();
            var alertIt = alert('Hello');
            setTimeout(alertIt,time);
        } 
    };
    foo.useValue();
    // log shows correct value
    console.log(foo.getValue());
    // returns a number
    console.log(typeof(foo.getValue()));
```

The alert does show up, but on load rather than using those 3 seconds.
It does log the correct value and also says it's a number so I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `useValue()` you call `alert('Hello')`, so it's executed immediately and the result is stored in `alertIt` variable. You should put it inside the function like this, as `setTimeout` expects a function as a first parameter:

```
var alertIt = function() {
    alert('Hello');
}

setTimeout(alertIt,time);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTiimeout` expects function and not variable. 
Also `var alertIt = alert('Hello');` this will return undefined.

Note: `var a = function()` will call it and assign return value. To assign a function to a variable with parameter, use `.bind`

Try `alert.bind(null, "hello");`

For demo purpose, I have hardcoded value of delay and commented `getValue` code.

```js
var foo = {
  getValue: function() {
    //var h1Text = $('h1').text();
    //h1Text = parseInt(h1Text);
    return true// h1Text;
  },
  useValue: function() {
    var time = 3000//this.getValue();
    var alertIt = alert.bind(null,'Hello');
    setTimeout(alertIt, time);
  }
};
foo.useValue();
// log shows correct value
console.log(foo.getValue());
// returns a number
console.log(typeof(foo.getValue()));
```